# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Газ поступает в счетчик сверху (,) через выходной патрубок и заставляет вращаться в противоположных направлениях два ротора, имеющих профиль восьмерки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. А если уж ставить (если вы считаете "через выходной патрубок" уточняющим членом), то надо ставить две. Но я бы не ставил.